# Where is WebLogic Jar containing javax.servlet in 10.3?

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to configure my path to include javax.servlet with WebLogic.
WebLogic has split out the Jar files, so which one contains javax.servlet?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Starting with WebLogic 10, BEA externalized the implementation of API specs from `weblogic.jar` into various "modules". 
They now bundle a new `api.jar` in  `{BEA_HOME}/wlsever_10.3/server/lib/` that contains just a `MANIFEST.MF` which points to `{BEA_HOME}/modules/*.jar`.

These modules include all API specifications as well as features provided BEA/ORACLE.

So, for Servlet API 2.5, indeed include `{BEA_HOME}/modules/javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar`.

Comment: Not does this answer my question but clarifies the api.jar.  I had seen it referenced but didn't under stand it since it is empty and why it didn't work in my dev environment.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found them.
For those that need answer they are located here:
$BEA_HOME/modules/javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar

Answer (score 1):

I don't do weblogic, so I can't point the exact location, but I can at least hint that JAR files are basically ZIP files which adhere a special folder structure and have a different extension. Knowing that fact, you should be able to use any ZIP tool to your taste to open/extract them and take a look in the folder/file structure yourself. To ease the job, you can also grab [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) which has a *Search* function with which you can search for folders and files in JAR files.

Comment: I am doing development on Linux so I don't have WinRAR.  But your approach was excellent and gave me a good idea. 
So I threw this bash command-line to accomplish the same thing.
for f in *.jar; do if jar -tf $f | grep -q javax.servlet; then echo $f; fi; done