# What weblogic jar file contains com.bea.logging.BaseLogRecord?

Tags: java, jar, weblogic, java.util.logging

In order to solve a build path issue, I am trying to figure out the Weblogic 10.3 library that contains com.bea.logging.BaseLogRecord

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this answer here to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1851801/425406

Comment: Thanks Sean. Although the answer did not help, it pointed me to the right directory "{BEA_HOME}/modules/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the jar, Thanks to Sean. For those who need answer, on Weblogic 10.3 the class is located in jar file $BEA_HOME/modules/com.bea.core.logging.1.8.0.0.jar.